Read csv files and partitioned write to parquet for time-series data
I'm trying to partitioning write the csv data that downloaded from binance to parquet.
For example, the kline of BNBUSDT and BTCUSDT with 1 second interval.The sample data sets start from Sep 1 to Sep 7 with per day per file.
def csv(source: str):
    source_path = pathlib.Path(source)
    if source_path.is_dir():
        for file_path in source_path.iterdir():
            write(file_path)
    else:
        write(source_path)

def write(path: pathlib.Path):
    stems = path.stem.split("-")
    duckdb.sql(
        f"""
        COPY (
            select
                '{stems[0]}' as symbol, 
                '{stems[1]}' as interval,
                year(epoch_ms(open_time)) as year,
                month(epoch_ms(open_time)) as month,
                *
                from read_csv('{path}',
                header=false,
                auto_detect=false,
                columns={{ 'open_time': 'BIGINT', 'open':'DOUBLE', 'high':'DOUBLE', 'low':'DOUBLE', 'close':'DOUBLE', 'volume':'DOUBLE', 'close_time':'INT64', 'quote_volume':'DOUBLE', 'count':'INT64', 'taker_buy_volume':'DOUBLE', 'taker_buy_quote_volume':'DOUBLE','ignore':'INT64'}}
            )
        ) to 'parquet' (
            FORMAT PARQUET,
            PARTITION_BY (interval,year,month),
            OVERWRITE_OR_IGNORE
        )
        """
    )

My current partition columns PARTITION_BY (interval, year, month). (Only for test purpose)
I have tried the following options.
OVERWRITE_OR_IGNORE only saves the last readed csv to parquet.
APPEND maps the csv to parquet files.(7 csv files generates 7 parquet files).
Looks like `APPEND` is what I need, but It doesn't handle the duplicated data.
My questions are

Which columns should I use for partition by？The parquet file size is about 2M (86400 rows) per day per symbol.

APPEND doesn't handle duplicated data. I may need to carefully update the data or clean the data. Do you guys use append or any other option combination.

What if I want to write stream data?


This is my first time using partition. Hope you guys can help..
